# Similarity matching between two arrays using Python 3.x

Tags: python, arrays

I am trying to match the elements of an 1D array with the elements of each column of a 2D matrix and save those elements of the array, which have a match in each column. I have tried this. But I am getting blank output file.(Few elements must have a match in each column)

```
    outfile = open("O.txt","w")

    infile1 = open("F1.txt","r")
    aline1=infile1.readlines()

    infile2 = open("F2.txt","r")
    var[]
    for line in infile2:
      var.append(line.strip().split(' '))

    for data1 in aline1:
      s=0
      for j in range(27):
        for i in range(484):
          if (data1==var[i][j]):
            s=s+1

      if (s==27):
        outfile.write("%s" %(data1))

    outfile.close()
    infile1.close()
    infile2.close()
```

Comment: Have you tried using the pandas library? This sort of thing is much easier loading the data into dataframes, rather than trying to use pure python

Comment: I think the `if (s==27):` should be inside the loop

Comment: Checkout `zip` to make your columns and `set` intersection to do the matching